# How to select the text "Maneten" using Selenium from the HTML screenshot?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to select and store the text "Maneten" from inside the "Pointer" class using Selenium. I have tried to select the class using the following code:
`name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='Pointer']")`

Unfortunately this results in the error code:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@class='Pointer']"}

Can anyone suggest how to select the text inside the "Pointer" class?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='pointer']").text
```

Lower case pointer and use .text. Also . is used only when referencing another element prior not root.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with XPATH? Just curious as I read that XPATH is slower in terms of performance and wanted to ask if there was a quicker way

Comment: Css selector a.pointer would be the fastest. Inside a webdriver wait with expected conditions presence of element if you really want performance.

Comment: Do you mind providing sample code for that so I can research it a bit more? Not exactly sure how to incorporate that into Selenium / Webdriver without seeing some code